# Update query with multiple where conditions

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am trying to update the row. Here I have multiple where conditions. This is the query I have tried.

```
$this->createQueryBuilder("jv")
->update()
->set("jv.pictureStatus", "?1")
->set("jv.pictureStatusId", "?2")
->andWhere("jv.aa = ?3")
->andWhere("jv.bb = ?4")
->andWhere("jv.cc = ?5")
->andWhere("jv.dd = ?6")
->andWhere("jv.ee = ?7")
->andWhere("jv.ff = ?8")
->andWhere("jv.gg = ?9")
->setParameter(1, "100")
->setParameter(2, "200")
->setParameter(3, $wheres["aa"])
->setParameter(4, $wheres["bb"])
->setParameter(5, $wheres["cc"])
->setParameter(6, $wheres["dd"])
->setParameter(7, $wheres["ee"])
->setParameter(8, $wheres["ff"])
->setParameter(9, $wheres["gg"])
->getQuery()->execute();
```

When I execute this query it returns 0 but nothing is getting updated.

Comment: If you change it for a select it returns something?

Comment: Yes its returning array

Comment: Anyways, I fix it by retrieving the primary id from the given where condition then later update using IN condition

Comment: Dump the data in $wheres, there must be something wrong in there then. Also is that select array empty or not?